# Android UTF-8 encoding not working?

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I am working with a CSV file right now. 
In my program i am using an OutputStreamWriter to write data the csv file.

```
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut, Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder());
```

I tried printing out the encoding style of this writer and get the following:

```
Log.i(TAG, "BODY ENCODING: " + myOutWriter.getEncoding());
Logcat: BODY ENCODING: UTF-8
```

But when i try to open the csv file on my desktop it says that the file is in windows-1252 so i cant read æøå chars which i need.

Am i missing something obvious here or am i not understanding the concept of outputStreamWriter? I have tried different types of encoding, but it doesn't seem to work :)

When i try to open in Excel:
[image: FilOprindelse = File Origin]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is actually UTF-8 not CP-1252. Your text editor/viewer detected it as CP-1251 (since no multi-byte characters). You can help your editor by adding byte order mark  (BOM) in the beginning of the file. I.e.

```
static final byte[] UTF8_BOM = {0xEF,0xBB,0xBF};
...
fOut.write(UTF8_BOM);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut, Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder());
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you man :) 

I added this line instead though after doing some research:
myOutWriter.write('\ufeff');

Thank you so much, i have been scratching my head of that!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening it in EXCEL? For EXCEL to recognize the file as UTF-8 it needs to have BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Hi! Yeah it is when i try to open it with excel it tells me that the file origin is 1252 - Western European(Windows)