# encode œ correctly with UTF-8 - java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am having problems to write out the following string into a file correctly. Especially with the character "œ". The Problem appears on my local machine (Windows 7) and on the server (Linux)

String: "Cœurs d’artichauts grillées"

1. Does Work ([œ gets displays correctly, while the apostrophe get translated into a question mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlMcK.png)):

   ```
   Files.write(path, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
   ```
2. Does not work ([result in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Ht6.png)):

   ```
   Files.write(path, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   ```

---

According to the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1), UTF-8 should be able to encode the œ correctly as well. Has anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: If the first method "works", it seems you don't want UTF-8. Because that one writes ISO-8859-1. Are you sure that whatever you use to display the output really wants UTF-8?

Comment: It is also possible that your String `content` is already broken. In case of a String literal, what is your Java source file encoding? It has to match what your editor thinks it should be.

Comment: @Thilo Problem found. The string was broken beforehand.
Broken String: "Curs d’artichauts grillées"
How it should look like: "Cœurs d’artichauts grillées"

EDIT: The broken String doesnt get shown here as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second approach works

```
String content = "Cœurs d’artichauts grillées";
Path path = Paths.get("out.txt");
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Is producing an `out.txt` file with:

```
Cœurs d’artichauts grillées
```

Most likely the editor you are using is not displaying the content correctly. You might have to force your editor to use the UTF-8 encoding and a font that displays œ and other UTF-8 characters. Notepad++ or IntelliJ IDEA work out of the box.

Comment: Don't forget about byte order mark (BOM) to help you text editor/viewer to auto-detect char set.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520409/android-utf-8-encoding-not-working/49520531#49520531

Comment: I am using those both tools, but i will check what you have said. thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @onionknight you can always inspect the file bytes with a hex editor to see how the content was written.

Comment: The BOM would be added as `Files.write(path, ("\uFEFF" + content).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: My mistake. Intellij made me think the original string was correct. I copied the string out of debug mode, which surprisingly worked.